# Is there a row limit for copying data into handsontable ?

Tags: javascript, handsontable

When copying sevreal thousand rows into `handsontable` from excel it throws

```
Uncaught Error: Security brake: Too much TRs. 
Please define height for your table, which will enforce scrollbars.
```

I set the height in the constructor

```
var options = { 
 height       : 340, 
 minSpareRows : 1,
 minSpareCols : 1,  
 colHeaders   : false,
 contextMenu  : true,
 columnSorting: true,
 ...
}
```

Same error - Is there any way to overcome this ?

Second, How can i catch this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran a quick test with handsontable, using 14 columns, I was able to load about 1200 rows. This is indicative of a cell number of about 16 000.

You can try lazy or delayed loading of data by adding a callback that is triggered on paste by handsontable.

Otherwise you can use the callback on paste to check the length of the data on the clipboard first and displaying an error if it is too big.

```
var clipText = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
```

This allows you to access text from the clipboard in javascript.

Comment: http://handsontable.com/demo/scroll.html - here they show an example with 100 000 rows, so this could be the solution for you. I forgot to mention it but the error was most definitely caused by pasting loads of data into the table

Comment: Hey @audiochick - Thanks for the response. I played around with the examples and it seems like `scrollV/H:auto` stabilizes this. Thing is - I want to display a spinner when pasting data into the grid, do you know if it's possible to catch the raw paste event from handsontable ? i tried `beforeChange` but i think it triggers prior to loading the gui and after the clip data has been processed - the processing is the time consuming part and the spinner should display before it begins.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your second question of displaying a scroller:

```
$("#myHandsontable").bind('paste', function () {
    $('#updateProgress').show();
});
```

Then in the constructor use the after change event:

```
$("#myHandsontable").handsontable({
    ...
    afterChange: function(changes, source) {
        if (source == "paste") {
            $('#UpdateProgress').hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Although you should try the latest version of handsontable, they really made a huge improvement in the time that it takes to paste data in the table.

Comment: is 0.10.3 the last version ?

Comment: Yes, 0.10.3 is the latest version

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue, it is a bit misleading due to the wording of the error,

> Error: Security brake: Too much TRs. Please define height for your
>   table, which will enforce scrollbars.

The error suggests that defining a height will force scroll bars, but in fact, I fixed it by defining a height that was small enough so scrollbars were forced on the table.

Hope my version makes more sense...
Everything seems to work fine then.